# libxml-ruby parse file and get required informations from xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-parsing, libxml-ruby

I am using libxml-ruby gem to read a xml string.

I am unable to extract the required info from xml string.

Currently i have following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message>
  <head>
    <api_key>252f5df2df522fg5fd25df2df5df2fd5</api_key>
    <user>123</user>
    <secret>********************</secret>
    <signature>****************</signature>
    <synchronization token="kj0s09ew090mv904v09409905b" last_synchronize_on="2010-01-02 11:30" />
  </head>
  <blockings>
    <blocking token="AAA" start_time="2010-01-01 10:00" end_time="2010-01-01 12:00" method="REQUEST" is_forced="FALSE" />
    <blocking token="BBB" start_time="2010-01-03 15:00" end_time="2010-01-03 18:00" method="REQUEST" is_forced="FALSE" />
  </blockings>
</message>
```

How do i get api_key, synchronization token, last_synchronize_on values from this xml string?

How do i get the info of the blocking nodes inside blockings node of this string?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use [LibXML::XML::Parser](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Parser.html) to get a [LibXML::XML::Document](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Document.html):

```
p = LibXML::XML::Parser.file(xml_file)
# or p = LibXML::XML::Parser.string(xml_string)
doc = p.parse
```

Then use [`find`](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Document.html#M000475) and a bit of XPath to find your nodes:

```
api_key_node = doc.find('//api_key').first
```

That gives you a [`LibXML::XML::Node`](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Node.html) in `api_key_node` so you can call [`content`](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Node.html#M000218) to get what you want:

```
api_key = api_key_node.content
# "252f5df2df522fg5fd25df2df5df2fd5"
```

Similar things apply to synchronization but you'd use `[]` to access the attribute values:

```
sync      = doc.find('//synchronization').first
token     = sync['token']
last_sync = sync['last_syncrhonize_on']
```

Same deal again for the `<blocking>` nodes but you'd iterate through them with `each` instead of using `first`.